# Script to filter the data based in the background color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to record a macro in Google Sheets to filter my data based in the Background color of the cells. To do that, I used the Record Macro tool and while I was recording, I applied the Filter Tool doing:
Turn on Filter >> Filter by color >> Fill color >> Pretended Color. However, when I go to the recorded script, for some reason, the criteria for the filter tool isn't there. After applying the filter I want to delete the rows with the pretended color, so if I apply the filter based in the script it will delete all the data, instead of only the data with the color.

After recording the macro, this is the script that I get:

```
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:O997').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('G6'));
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:O997').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G1').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .build(); // as you can see the variable criteria isn't defined with the fill color
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(7, criteria);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you so much!

Comment: The code that you obtained can generate the [filter view](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) that you have previously created. If you delete the `filter view` with the second last icon in the menu bar, you can recreate it by running the script. If you want to delete some cells with a specific color forever, I recommend you to write some code in Apps Script. I can help you with that if you provide me an example of how your data looks like and how do you want the final result.

Comment: @fullfine thanks for the help! In fact, I'm trying to write some code in Apps Script but, as I'm not a specialist, I was trying to record a macro and then review it to do exactly what I wanted. I already have a script to identify duplicates, filling them with a certain color and copy them to another sheet, just to garantee I'm not deleting data by mistake. what I wanted to do after that was deleting the data forever from the original sheet. When I identify the duplicates, I fill the cells with the name of the person in question, but what I want to do is delete all the corresponding row

Comment: If you want to delete some rows you can use [deleteRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition). It takes the index position of the row. To offer you more detailed help please update the question with the updated code and explaining where exactly you have doubts.